# Setting Tomcat to Cooperate with the Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat

hello in my VPS i have both APACHE(PORT 80) & APACHE TOMCAT(PORT 8080) my principale website run on tomcat(domain.com) my question is :

is there a methode to cooperate both tomcat and apache ?

domain.com =>take me to my principale website hosted on Tomcat

domain.com/siteapache OR  siteapache.domain.com => take me to a website hosted on apache

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to implement this is to let apache httpd be in front and delegate the request.

Here is a tutorial on how to configure tomcat.

https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

Using `VirtualHosts` in apache control the flow of traffic. Se this example:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: thnk u finaly i found a way to make  tomcat execute PHP code  http://www.studytrails.com/blog/php-on-a-java-app-server-apache-tomcat-using-quercus/